# How to move the canvas(axes) with clicking moving cursor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want the cursor to drag the canvas/axes (clicking and moving)

I'm not familiar with matplotlib and python coding, any instruction will be highly appreciated!!!

```
fig = plt.figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(fig)
canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: self.onPress(event, fig, canvas))
canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', lambda event: self.onRelease(event, canvas))

def onPress(self, event, fig, canvas):
  canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', lambda event: self.onMove(event, fig))

def onMove(self, event, fig):
  axtemp = event.inaxes
  x_min, x_max = axtemp.get_xlim()
  y_min, y_max = axtemp.get_ylim()
  if event.button == 1:
    x_mouse, y_mouse = event.xdata, event.ydata
    axtemp.set...?  '''from there I have no idea'''

def onRelease(self, event, canvas):
  canvas.mpl_disconnect(canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.onMove))
```

I have a thought that the problem is to measure the moving distance of the cursor from time to time and use `fig.canvas.draw_idle()`, but I don't know how to.

I saw the notice that comment should be meaningful, so thanks in advance!

Comment: `axtemp` is event  value `event.inaxes` so setting `axtemp.set()` can't change canvas.

Comment: I alwasy thought that `FigureCanvasQTAgg` already have built-in this functionality `drag the canvas/axes`. And as I rember it has even ToolBar with buttons for this. But maybe it was in different module for plots - like `plotly` or `bokeh`

Comment: @furas Actually I'm using it in PyQt5 interface, so I need to drag it in a QWidget. The works I have done in the figure(canvas) will also work after `QWidget.addWidget(figure.canvas)`

Comment: usualy when I had to something like this - first I saved position in `onPress`, next in `onMove` I get current position and calculate difference to see how much it moved like `dx`,`dy` in example [Draggable rectangle exercise](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html#draggable-rectangle-exercise) in Matplotlib documentation, and I used it to change positon, and finally I keep current position to use it next time in `onMove`

Comment: @furas I used the `axtemp.set()` in the part of zoom def, it really works and also dynamically with scroll, maybe it's because of `fig.canvas.draw_idle()`?

Comment: I think you would have to use `set_xlim( x_min - dx, x_max - dx )`

Comment: @furas `axtemp.set(xlim=(x_min + dx, x_max - dx))` it's what I usedIt also works in PyCharm maybe some deprecated version?..  And your above suggest seems great! I will try that now!

Comment: frankly, I found image https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfVp3.png  which shows it with built-in toolbar and there is button for moving (panning) and zooming - so it already has these functions. Source code: [python - matplotlib toolbar in a pyqt5 application - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140576/matplotlib-toolbar-in-a-pyqt5-application)

Comment: @furas Oh my god, that's very helpful information, I was debugging just now, Thanks a lot for your help!